# Convert GeoSeries to regular float type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, geopandas

I am trying to convert a column of a GeoDataFrame object containing numpy float64 datatypes into an array of regular float types. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without iterating through the entire column?

```
trajectory_features['points'][fid] = gdf[key]
```

Is what I have to far, but when I try to serialize it to JSON it gives the error that the numpy data type float64 is not JSON serializable.
gdf is the GeoDataFrame and trajectory_features is a 2 dimensional dictionary.

Comment: BTW, if you are converting it to *Geo*JSON (and not some custom json format), you can use the built in `to_json` method

Comment: sadly it is being converted to a custom JSON format so I can't use to_json in this instance @joris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tolist` method, which will convert the array or Series to a python list, and the values itself are then converted to regular python floats as well:

```
trajectory_features['points'][fid] = gdf[key].tolist()
```

See the [`ndarray.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) docs (the `pandas.Series.tolist()` method used above is equivalent to it)

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.ndarray.tolist(trajectory_features)` to convert your numpy array into a regular list containing your floats.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Psy's answer I was able to solve the problem.

My code:

```
trajectory_features['points'][fid] = numpy.ndarray.tolist(gdf[key].values)
```

Comment: A bit shorter and cleaner, you can also do `gdf[key].tolist()`

Comment: Seems to work as well and I like your answer better as it's easier to understand. Frustrating that I didn't think of something so simple on my own. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it as the solution. @joris